# All field type names are lowercase after using materialize from QgsFeatureSource in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, fields-attributes

An interesting fact, after using the [`materialize()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureSource.html#ab95bcca99b1d5c082ca409da04e280b9) method over my original `QgsVectorLayer` with the following code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for field in layer.fields():
    print(f"Field '{field.name()}' has '{field.typeName()}' type")
    
new_layer = layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(layer.allFeatureIds()))

for field in new_layer.fields():
    print(f"Field '{field.name()}' has '{field.typeName()}' type")
```

Apparently, all of the field type names become now lowercase, e.g. `'String' => 'string'` etc.

Can someone confirm this trait? Otherwise, explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of Memory Layer Field types.

Look at this part of the `QgsVectorLayer.materialize` [function C++ code](https://api.qgis.org/api/qgsfeaturesource_8cpp_source.html#l00156):

```cpp
std::unique_ptr< QgsVectorLayer > layer( QgsMemoryProviderUtils::createMemoryLayer(
    sourceName(),
    outFields,
    outWkbType,
    crs ) );
```

it calls `QgsMemoryProviderUtils::createMemoryLayer` and if you look at [the code of this method](https://api.qgis.org/api/qgsmemoryproviderutils_8cpp_source.html#l00063):

```cpp
QString memoryLayerFieldType( QVariant::Type type )
{
  switch ( type )
  {
    case QVariant::Int:
      return QStringLiteral( "integer" );
 
    case QVariant::LongLong:
      return QStringLiteral( "long" );
 
    case QVariant::Double:
      return QStringLiteral( "double" );
 
    case QVariant::String:
      return QStringLiteral( "string" );
 
    case QVariant::Date:
      return QStringLiteral( "date" );
 
    case QVariant::Time:
      return QStringLiteral( "time" );
 
    case QVariant::DateTime:
      return QStringLiteral( "datetime" );
 
    case QVariant::ByteArray:
      return QStringLiteral( "binary" );
 
    case QVariant::Bool:
      return QStringLiteral( "boolean" );
 
    case QVariant::Map:
      return QStringLiteral( "map" );
 
    default:
      break;
  }
  return QStringLiteral( "string" );
}
```

the lowercase field type is explicit, you have in a `QgsVectorLayer`, not in memory, a Qt Field type and then, for memory layer provider, a literal string.

Comment: So, simply saying a memory layer simply overwrites original layer field types, is not it?